# Custom camera displays preview in wrong orientation and zoomed image android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working with **simple custom camera** , that takes pictures on button click.

The camera displays the preview in **wrong orientation (landscape)**, even when the phone is in portrait ,as well as the image appears some what zoomed .

I `googled` it and found many solution to this problem , I tried everything , but no one worked in my case.

I think I am missing some main concepts , which I couldn't figure it out

[image]

**CameraActivity.java**

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private PictureCallback mPictureCallback;
    private Context myContext;
    private FrameLayout cameraPreview;
    private boolean frontCamera = false, backCamera = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        initialize();
    }

    private void findViews() {
        cameraPreview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    }

    public void initialize() {
        findViews();
        myContext = this;
        mCamera = Camera.open(findBackFacingCamera());
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(myContext, mCamera);
        cameraPreview.addView(mPreview);
    }

    private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1; // initialized with empty
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                cameraId = i;
                frontCamera = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    private int findBackFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1; // initialized with empty
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                cameraId = i;
                backCamera = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //mPictureCallback=getPi
        if (!hasCamera(myContext)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Sorry, your phone does not have a camera!");
        }
        if (mCamera == null) {
            if (findFrontFacingCamera() == 1) {
                releaseCamera();
                chooseCamera();
            }
        }
    }

    private void chooseCamera() {
        // If currently front camera is opened,then switch to back camera
        if (frontCamera) {
            int cameraId = findBackFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId > 0) {
                // Open backfacing camera
                // Set picture callback
                // refresh the preview
                mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                mPictureCallback = getPictureCallBack();
                mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
            }
        } else {
            int cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId > 0) {
                mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                mPictureCallback = getPictureCallBack();
                mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
            }
        }
    }

    private PictureCallback getPictureCallBack() {
        PictureCallback pictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {


                File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
                if (pictureFile == null) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    fos.write(data);
                    fos.close();
                    Log.e(TAG, " picture saved at " + pictureFile.getName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, " getPictureCallBack  " + e);
                }
                mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
            }
        };
        return pictureCallback;
    }

    private File getOutputMediaFile() {
        // make a new storage directory inside sd card
        File mediaStorage = new File("/sdcard/", "Tootle Camera");

        // if Tootle Camera directory doesn't exist
        if (!mediaStorage.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorage.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            } else {
                mediaStorage.mkdirs();
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy_hh:mm:ss a").format(new Date());

        // make media file
        File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorage.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        return mediaFile;
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasCamera(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();
    }
}
```

**CameraPreview.java**

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";
        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;
        private boolean isPreviewRunning = false;

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            mCamera = camera;
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            try {
                // create the surface and start camera previre
                if (mCamera == null) {
                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                    mCamera.startPreview();

                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, " surfaceCreated " + e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
            // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
            //refreshCamera(mCamera);

            if (isPreviewRunning) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }

            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

            if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(height, width);
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            }

            if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
            }

            if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(height, width);
            }

            if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
            }

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            previewCamera();

        }

        public void refreshCamera(Camera camera) {

            if (mHolder == null) {
                // preview surface does not exist
                return;
            }
            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, " refreshCamera " + e);
            }
            setCamera(camera);
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, " refreshCamera " + e);
            }
        }

        private void setCamera(Camera camera) {
            //method to set a camera instance
            mCamera = camera;
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            mCamera.release();
        }

        public void previewCamera() {
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                isPreviewRunning = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Cannot start preview " + e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not use the size of preview surface to setPreviewSize of your camera. You should iterate through getSupportedPreviewSizes for the best match. To choose portrait orientation of the camera live preview, use camera.setDisplayOrientation().

Answer (score 1):

in your **CameraPreview.java**

After

```
setCamera(camera);
try {
      mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
```

write this:

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
mCamera.startPreview();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have file path and bitmap Use the below method to check rotation and fix it:

```
  public Bitmap checkRotation(String filePath, Bitmap scaledBitmap) {
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return scaledBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: The screen shot is not of a captured image, but a live camera preview.